# Magento2.4: How to display image with custom image role in category page instead of small image role?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, magento2.4.3

I want to display images with a custom role as shown in pictures, now I want to show those images instead of images with a small role on the category page, and I want to do this programmatically?
I want to show an image with the custom attribute role that I assigned.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to show Top Banner or Top Banner Left image for category pages products?

Comment: yes, I want to display images that have those top banner image role on the category page.

Comment: If you set that role that it will show for all products on category page and if doesn't have that image that it will not show any image.

Comment: how to do this programmatically?

Comment: Wait let me check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by following steps:

**Step 1:**

Add the below code to your theme view.xml under

```
<images module="Magento_Catalog">
```

Code:

```
<image id="product_top_banner" type="top_banner">
    <width>240</width>
    <height>300</height>
</image>
```

Where top_banner is your attribute code.
[image]

**Step 2:**

Now open your **list.phtml** and add the below code just after the **foreach** started

```
if ($_product->getTopBanner()) {
    $imageDisplayArea = 'product_top_banner';
}
```

[image]
product_top_banner will the id which you have added on **view.xml**

**Step 3:**
Also run this query in your database, this is for use the attribute in product listing:

> UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute SET used_in_product_listing=1 where
> attribute_id=(SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE
> `attribute_code`='top_banner' and `entity_type_id` = 4);

Hope this helps!

Comment: i used your code in custom module and its giving me error, "  1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The XML in file "/var/www/html/trainingtasks/app/code/Other/ImageRole/etc/view.xml" is invalid:
Element 'images': This element is not expected.
Line: 4 "

Comment: The the code in your theme's etc/view.xml

Comment: i resolved the " image element not expected " issue as I was missing a media element in view file

Answer (score 2):

Magento shows products which are having type as a `small_image` on the category page. This can vary depending on 3rd party theme.

Worth to check type in the `etc/view.xml` available at the theme level.

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
    <width>240</width>
    <height>300</height>
</image>
<image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
    <width>240</width>
    <height>300</height>
</image>
```

Change `type="small_image"` to the role which you want to show.

*Type value will be the attribute code of image type.*

You have to find the code of the **Top Banner** Image role may be from the Product Attributes section.

Run the `bin/magento clear:cache` with `bin/magento setup:upgrade` should change the image on category pages.

ID `category_page_grid` is for Grid mode and `category_page_list` for list mode.

Comment: if I try to do this in a custom module, I cant use the image tag In the view.xml  file? any hints on how to do this in a custom module?

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The XML in file "/var/www/html/trainingtasks/app/code/Other/ImageRole/etc/view.xml" is invalid:
Element 'images': This element is not expected.
Line: 4

Answer (score 0):

> **
> The Complete Code

**

**Vendor\Module\etc\view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="product_top_banner" type="top_banner_image">
                <width>100</width>
                <height>100</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

**Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml**

```
 <?php  if ($_product->getTopBannerImage()) {
                        $imageDisplayArea = 'product_top_banner';
                        }
                        else
                            $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_grid';
                      ?>
```

put this code inside foreach function as shown above one of the answers